# Custom directive is not working inside angular module?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive, angular-module

In my app, i have two modules. `IdentityModule and ServiceModule`. They are loaded as lazyloading technology.

Now I have created a custom directive `IconSpacerDirective` that is bind with `app.module.ts`. It's working fine inside my `app.component.ts`.

But it's not working inside the `IdentityModule`. I am having this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type IconSpacerDirective is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and IdentityRegistryModule! Please consider moving IconSpacerDirective to a higher module that imports AppModule and IdentityRegistryModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes IconSpacerDirective then import that NgModule in AppModule and IdentityRegistryModule.
Error: Type IconSpacerDirective is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and IdentityRegistryModule! Please consider moving IconSpacerDirective to a higher module that imports AppModule and IdentityRegistryModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes IconSpacerDirective then import that NgModule in AppModule and IdentityRegistryModule.
```

Here is my `identityRegistryModule`:

```
import { IconSpacerDirective } from '../shared/custom-directive/icon-spacer.directive';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    IconSpacerDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    IdentityRegistryRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule   

  ],
  providers: [
    IdentityService,
  ],
})
export class IdentityRegistryModule { }
```

my `app.module.ts` as follows:

```
import { IconSpacerDirective } from './shared/custom-directive/icon-spacer.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MainNavComponent,
    SideNavComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    IconSpacerDirective,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MaterialModule,
    OAuthModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  //exports: [IconSpacerDirective]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

How can i use the `IconSpacerDirective` inside my `identityRegistryModule`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the `IconSpacerDirective` in both the `AppModule` and the `IdentityRegistryModule`, then you need to create a separate module for that directive that you can then import in the modules where you need it.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [IconSpacerDirective],
  exports: [IconSpacerDirective]
})
export class IconSpacerModule { }
```

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [IconSpacerModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [IconSpacerModule]
})
export class IdentityRegistryModule { }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. so it's not sufficient if i just import the directive inside my module? @sam-Herrmann

Comment: No, you cannot import directives/components. You can only import modules. Once you import the module, you will have access to the directives/components that the imported module exports.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are importing the module you don't need to explicitly declare it again. Remove it from the declarations of `IdentityRegistryModule` as that is what the error clearly states.

In the app.module, export the `IconSpacerDirective`

```
@NgModule({
  ...
  exports: [IconSpacerDirective] // so that it can be used when this module is imported
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and import the app.module in `identityRegistryModule`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IdentityRegistryRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    AppModule  
  ]
  ...
})
export class IdentityRegistryModule { }
```

Comment: thanks for the idea. But will it increase the size of `identityRegistryModule` by importing the whole `app.module` into `identityRegistryModule`? just want to know. @nicholas-k

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the directive only in IdentityModule then no need to add it in App.module. Declare it in Identity module and use it. But if you want to use the directive in multiple modules including components in app.module then create separate module for common directives like:

**common directive module**

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [IconSpacerDirective],
 exports:[IconSpacerDirective]
})
export class MyCommonModule{}
```

Then export it where ever you want. Lets suppose you want to use it for the component in app.module as well component in Identity module the follow below logic:

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
imports: [MyCommonModule]
})
```

**identiyt.module.ts**

import { IconSpacerDirective } from '../shared/custom-directive/icon-spacer.directive';

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IdentityRegistryRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    **MyCommonModule**
  ],
  providers: [
    IdentityService,
  ],
})
export class IdentityRegistryModule { }
```